# Can Windows IIS settings be managed from the command line?

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I've gone through a plethora of GUIs to setup a new IIS instance with some custom settings. I'm aware of web.config in my wwwroot but that does not reflect all the changes I've made.

Is there a way to export the current state of IIS for re-use and then later setup a new server with the same settings, from the command line? I'd like to avoid hours of clicking through GUIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [appcmd.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635852(v=ws.11).aspx). It allows you to manage everything in IIS, including [backing up and restoring the configuration](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/954872).

There are also many [PowerShell cmdlets for managing IIS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh867899(v=wps.630).aspx); these also includes ones for backing up and restoring the configuration.

Comment: As well the PowerShell flavored version [`Backup-WebConfiguration`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790558.aspx).